# Getting a composition serie of dihedral group $D_8$ and identify simple groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Getting a composition serie of  dihedral group $D_8$ and identify
>   simple groups.

This subject is related to Jordan-Hölder theorem.

I'm a bit confused on this problem. Is anyone is able to give me a good hint?

Comment: The following [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259474/composition-series-for-dihedral-groups) should help you.

Comment: There are seven composition series for $D_8$, with simple factors $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: Doesn't one usually omit trivial quotients in a composition series?