# Composition series of $D_{12}$ (of order $12$).

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

I find that $$\{id,\langle r^2\rangle, \langle r\rangle,D_{12}\}$$ and $$\{id,\langle r^3\rangle, \langle r\rangle,D_{12}\}$$ are composition series.

Are there any more composition series of $D_{12}$?

What about Sylow $2$-subgroup - could be in composition series?

Comment: Have a look at this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3476217/how-many-composition-series-of-group-d6-are-there-dihedral-group-order-12) answer, (note that they use the notation $D_6$ to refer to the dihedral group of order 12, but its the same group).

Comment: I see - thank you